# What is the best way to solve this high school exercise?

Tags: calculus, education

Can you share with me how would you best solve this exersise to a high school student?

Show that $f(x)=x^2-6x+2$ , $x\in(-\infty,3]$ is $1-1$ and find its inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** To prove the function is 1-1 use the definition

> $$ f(x_1)=f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2 .$$

Answer (score 6):

Complete the square: $$f(x)=(x-3)^2-7$$

This is a parabola, pointing upward, with vertex at $(3,-7)$.  You can graph it to supply the "show" portion.  Then,

$$y=(x-3)^2-7$$
$$y+7=(x-3)^2$$
$$\sqrt{y+7}=|x-3|=3-x$$
(since $x<3$)
$$x=3-\sqrt{y+7}$$
So $f(x)=3-\sqrt{x+7}$ is the inverse.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what vadim123 has written, by showing $f(x)$ is one-to-one in that domain, assume there are two $u, v\in(-\infty, 3]$ such that

$$\begin{align*}
f(u) =& f(v)\\
u^2 - 6u + 2 =& v^2 - 6v + 2\\
u^2 - v^2 =& 6u - 6v\\
(u-v)(u+v-6) =& 0
\end{align*}$$

So either $u=v$, or $u+v = 6$. For the second case, since $u\le 3$ from the domain,
$$v=6-u\ge6-3=3$$
this makes $v=3$ and hence $u=6-v = 3=v$. Anyway $f(u)=f(v)$ implies $u=v$.